# How to auth a bitnami/redis installed by helm?

Tags: redis, kubernetes-helm

I installed bitnami/redis using helm with default parameters. However, I was refused to use it with NOAUTH error. It gived me tips to get an ACL name and password, but I don't know how?

I issued the cmd
`helm install redis bitnami/redis`
,and tried like this

````
127.0.0.1:6379> auth ""
(error) WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair or user is disabled.
127.0.0.1:6379> auth default ""
(error) WRONGPASS invalid username-password pair or user is disabled.
127.0.0.1:6379> ACL list
(error) NOAUTH Authentication required.```
````

Comment: I reinstalled it again, and found some tips to get passward `export REDIS_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace default redis -o jsonpath="{.data.redis-password}" | base64 --decode)`, and run `redis-cli -h redis-master -a $REDIS_PASSWORD`, it connected successfully but auth failed. `Warning: AUTH failed`

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else struggling with this, you can disable authentication when deploying redis using helm.

```
helm install redis bitnami/redis --set auth.enabled=false
```